# C# NetworkStream.Read reads more than specified

Tags: c#

40-50 on the package, the program reads 2 - 4 bytes greater than the specified (temp), what could be wrong?

```
size =  nsgsout.Read(buf, 0, 2);

while (size != 2)
{
  size += nsgsout.Read(buf, size, 2 - size);
}

temp = (buf[0] + buf[1] * 256);
size = nsgsout.Read(buf, 2, temp - 2);

while (size != temp - 2)
{
    size += nsgsout.Read(buf, size + 2, temp - size + 2);
}
```

Comment: What does "40-50 on the package" means? Package of what? 40-50 liters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this does what you think it does:

```
temp - size+2
```

I suspect you expect it to mean:

```
temp - (size + 2)
```

But it's really equivalent to

```
(temp - size) + 2
```

I suspect you really want the call to be:

```
size += nsgsout.Read(buf, size + 2, temp - size - 2);
```

Also note that you can change this:

```
size = nsgsout.Read(buf, 2, temp - 2);
```

to just

```
size = 0;
```

and just go into the loop and let that the first read too...

Answer (score 0):

2-size can be a negative number.  You probably need to read size - 2 instead?!